# a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object (parent class problems)

Tags: c++

I am trying to access this function, which is within a parent class of my derived class. I am having trouble accessing it and keep receiving the error message `a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object` at **Line 18** `if (Netflix::searchCategory(name) != NULL` Does anyone know the issue I am having?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include "project.h"

using namespace std;

Netflix::Netflix()
{
    front = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    front->data = "";
    front->next = NULL;
    front->prev = NULL;
}

void Netflix::Category::addMovie(string name) // Add Movie In The Begining to a Category
{
    if (Netflix::searchCategory(name) != NULL)
    {
    }
}
```

This is the Project.h that is referred too in the cpp file.

```
struct Netflix
{

    Netflix();
    struct node *front = NULL;
    void addCategory();    // Add Category to Category List
    struct node *searchCategory(string name); // Search for Category
    void searchMovie();    // Search Movie by Name
    void rmvCategory();    // Remove Category by Name
    void deleteMovies();   // Delete All Movies By Date
    void printAll();

    struct Category
    {
        void addMovie(string name); // Add Movie to a Category
        void printCate();           // Print all Movies of This Category
        void getIndex();            // Get Movies Index (Array)
        void searchmovie_cate();    // Search a Movie within a Category
    };                                      // Print All Movies by All Category
};
```

I understand my question wasn't clear the first time. Hopefully my edits make it a bit better to read sorry for that headache.

Comment: What is the error message you're getting? Your `Netflix` struct doesn't _have_ a method called `searchCategory` that accepts a single `string` as an argument, it only has a no-args method `searchCategory()`. It's also not clear what you want the `Netflix::Netflix()` to mean. Are you trying to create a temporary default-constructed `Netflix` object and call `searchCategory` on that temporary?

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Microsoft's? After filling in some missing pieces, both gcc and clang gave error messages that referred specifically to "constructor" rather than "nonstatic member reference".

Comment: What I am trying to do is access Netflix's function "searchCategory" inside Categories function: "addMovie". I have changed the code to look like `if(Netflix::searchCategory(name) != NULL) {}` also in my project.h file, I have changed the argument in `struct Netflix` to have a `string name` as an input.

Comment: @JaMiT Hey JaMiT, I believe that constructor issue has actually caught up with me haha. I managed to fix the problem above, but it looks like my Category constructor is not working correctly? I have no error messages, but when my code goes to compile it just ends up stopping after I call `Category "Category name"`. I guess I'm hoping you might have a solution on your end?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that It was in a problem within my Project.h file. I wasn't creating a parent class correctly. I ended up switching the way I made category a derived class by doing `struct Category : public Netflix`. Instead of just throwing it inside `Netflix struct`.

Comment: Public inheritance is used to model an is-a relationship, and I would expect that a `Category` is not a `Netfix`. Perhaps this allowed your code to compile, but it seems to me it's probably not achieving what you're trying to do.

Comment: @JohnIlacqua I basically need my Category struct to be able to use the Netflix functions. Because I need to connect, eventually, the categories I create in the Netflix struct to the movies I will end up creating in the Category struct. Do you know of another way to do this? It's connected a doubly linked list (categories), to a circular linked list (movies).

Comment: But how is the `Netflix` object itself used? What `Netflix` instance is the `Category` supposed to be accessing? The general idea is that you need a reference to a specific `Netflix` object instance to be able to call `searchCategory` on it.

Comment: @JohnIlacqua I'm not sure if I understood your question 100%. But I need the Category function : `addMovie()` to access the `Netflix searchCategory` function because `addMovie` needs to know where in my linked list to add said movie.